# Cannot subscribe on slickgrid scroll event

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using slickgrid as container for data, and trying to subscribe on it's onscroll event as of described in documentation, i.e.

```
task_list.onscroll.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    console.log('scrolling occured');
});
```

Actually, I'm trying to do other processing afterwards, which is translating contents of the web page. The content is not fully translated, so I need to translate each time I scroll the page. However I get the message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

How can I troubleshoot this error and find out why I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few small errors in your code, first the event names are camelCase so it should be `onScroll` and second if you want to subscribe to SlickGrid events then you need to use the grid object

```js
grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e, args) {
 // ...
});
```

and don't forget to unsubscribe when leaving the page because you'll have quite a leak with the onScroll. I prefer to use the Slick EventHandler since it has an easier `unsubscribeAll` method that I can use when destroying/leaving the page

```js
var eventHandler = new Slick.EventHandler();
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

function something() {  
  eventHandler.subscribe(grid.onScroll, function(e, args) {
    // ...
  });
}

function destroy() {
  eventHandler.unsubscribeAll();
}
```

Hopefully there's no error in my code but just to let you know I wrote by memory here so please double-check the code and look at the multiple SlickGrid [Examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) which all have easy code access